# PowerQuery Fill missing dates and data

Tags: powerquery

How can you get PowerQuery to:

1. Generate the missing dates
2. Fill the missing dates with the previous most recent values

Desired input and output are outlined below:

**Input**

```
+------------+------+-------+
|DATE        | CUR  | RATE  |
+------------+------+-------+
| 01-01-2019 | EUR  | 0.7   |
| 01-01-2019 | USD  | 0.8   |
| 03-01-2019 | EUR  | 0.71  |
| 03-01-2019 | USD  | 0.81  |
```

**Output**

```
+------------+------+-------+
|DATE        | CUR  | RATE  |
+------------+------+-------+
| 01-01-2019 | EUR  | 0.7   |
| 01-01-2019 | USD  | 0.8   |
| 02-01-2019 | EUR  | 0.7   |
| 02-01-2019 | USD  | 0.8   |
| 03-01-2019 | EUR  | 0.71  |
| 03-01-2019 | USD  | 0.81  |
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below

(a) pivot original data (b) creates all dates from min to max of original list (c) removes duplicates (d) appends missing dates to original table (e) uses fill...down to populate (f) unpivots

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"DATE", type number}, {"CUR", type text}, {"RATE", Int64.Type}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[CUR]), "CUR", "RATE", List.Sum),
List = Table.FromList(List.Difference({List.Min(#"Changed Type"[DATE])  .. List.Max(#"Changed Type"[DATE])},#"Changed Type"[DATE]), Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null,null),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(List,{{"Column1", "DATE"}}),
Combined= #"Pivoted Column" & #"Renamed Columns",
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Combined,{{"DATE", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Sorted Rows",{"EUR", "USD"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filled Down",{{"DATE", type date}}),
#"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type1", {"DATE"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in #"Unpivoted Columns"
```