# Fill in missing cumulative values by date with multiple dimensions in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

In Power Query, given a table with cumulative values (`Cumulative Unique Count`) based on dates (`Start of Week`) which require filling down, how can the missing rows be generated if it has multiple dimension/attribute columns? Other value columns (`Count` and `Unique Count in Week`) in the table should be filled in as null or 0.

Example table:

| Criteria One | Criteria Two | Start of Week | Count | Unique Count in Week | Cumulative Unique Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | 3/22/2020 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| A | C | 3/29/2020 | 9 | 3 | 4 |
| A | C | 4/5/2020 | 3 | 2 | 5 |
| A | C | 4/12/2020 | 10 | 8 | 9 |
| A | D | 3/22/2020 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| A | D | 4/5/2020 | 8 | 5 | 6 |
| A | D | 4/12/2020 | 2 | 3 | 9 |
| B | C | 3/29/2020 | 6 | 4 | 4 |
| B | C | 4/12/2020 | 12 | 9 | 10 |
| B | D | 3/29/2020 | 8 | 4 | 4 |
| B | D | 4/5/2020 | 6 | 6 | 7 |
| B | D | 4/12/2020 | 9 | 7 | 9 |

The result should be something like this (without the `Comment` column):

| Criteria One | Criteria Two | Start of Week | Count | Unique Count in Week | Cumulative Unique Count | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | C | 3/22/2020 | 4 | 1 | 1 |  |
| A | C | 3/29/2020 | 9 | 3 | 4 |  |
| A | C | 4/5/2020 | 3 | 2 | 5 |  |
| A | C | 4/12/2020 | 10 | 8 | 9 |  |
| A | D | 3/22/2020 | 3 | 3 | 3 |  |
| A | D | **3/29/2020** | 0 | 0 | 3 | Fill down |
| A | D | 4/5/2020 | 8 | 5 | 6 |  |
| A | D | 4/12/2020 | 2 | 3 | 9 |  |
| B | C | **3/22/2020** | 0 | 0 | 0 | Fill |
| B | C | 3/29/2020 | 6 | 4 | 4 |  |
| B | C | **4/5/2020** | 0 | 0 | 4 | Fill down |
| B | C | 4/12/2020 | 12 | 9 | 10 |  |
| B | D | **3/22/2020** | 0 | 0 | 0 | Fill |
| B | D | 3/29/2020 | 8 | 4 | 4 |  |
| B | D | 4/5/2020 | 6 | 6 | 7 |  |
| B | D | 4/12/2020 | 9 | 7 | 9 |  |

Pivoting, filling down, then unpivoting like suggested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/hbm6dg/power_query_how_to_fill_in_missing_dates_in/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808865/2891365) won't work because there's more than one criteria and the criteria sometimes contains nulls.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different Power Query Approach:

- Create a list of ALL the possible weeks
- Group by the Criteria
- Create a subTable for each group

  - Create a list of the Missing Weeks
  - For each missing week, create a Record whereby

    - The Criteria are carried over from the group
    - The Date is incremented according to the missing week list
    - the various counts are set to Null (*you could set the to zero if you prefer, or anything else by changing the value in the List.Generate function*)
- Then expand the subTables and set the Type

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Criteria One", type text}, {"Criteria Two", type text}, {"Start of Week", type date}, 
        {"Count", Int64.Type}, {"Unique Count in Week", Int64.Type}, {"Cumulative Unique Count", Int64.Type}}),

//create a list of all the possible weeks
    wkFirst = List.Min(#"Changed Type"[Start of Week]),
    wkLast = List.Max(#"Changed Type"[Start of Week]),
    numWeeks = Duration.Days(wkLast-wkFirst)/7+1,
    allWeeks = List.Dates(wkFirst,numWeeks,#duration(7,0,0,0)),

//Group; then add missing weeks to each sub-table    
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Criteria One", "Criteria Two"}, {
        {"All", each _, type table [Criteria One=nullable text, Criteria Two=nullable text, Start of Week=nullable date, Count=nullable number, Unique Count in Week=nullable number, Cumulative Unique Count=nullable number]},
        {"with All weeks", each if Table.RowCount(_) = List.Count(allWeeks) then _

            //create the subtables whereby we fill in the missing weeks
            //and create a record for the missing weeks whereby the Criteria are carried over
            //and the Counts are "nulled".
            //if you want to make the counts Zero, just change that within the List.Generate function
                else Table.Sort(
                        Table.Combine({_,   
                    let 
                        missingWeeks = List.RemoveMatchingItems(allWeeks, [Start of Week]),
                        startDts = List.Generate(()=>
                            [Counter =0, Criteria One= [Criteria One]{0}, Criteria Two= [Criteria Two]{0}, Start of Week=missingWeeks{0}, Count=null, Unique Count in Week=null, Cumulative Unique Count=null],
                            each [Counter] < List.Count(missingWeeks),
                            each [Counter = [Counter]+1, Criteria One=[Criteria One], Criteria Two=[Criteria Two], Start of Week=missingWeeks{[Counter]+1}, Count=null, Unique Count in Week=null, Cumulative Unique Count=null])
                    in

                        //Remove the "Counter" column from the Combined subtable
                        //Then Sort by "Start of Week"
                        Table.RemoveColumns(Table.FromRecords(startDts),"Counter")}),
                        {"Start of Week"})
                        }
        }),

//Remove Extra Columns, then expand the subtable, and type it
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Criteria One", "Criteria Two", "All"}),
    #"Expanded with All weeks" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "with All weeks", {"Criteria One", "Criteria Two", "Start of Week", "Count", "Unique Count in Week", "Cumulative Unique Count"}, {"Criteria One", "Criteria Two", "Start of Week", "Count", "Unique Count in Week", "Cumulative Unique Count"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded with All weeks",{{"Criteria One", type text}, {"Criteria Two", type text}, {"Start of Week", type date}, {"Count", Int64.Type}, {"Unique Count in Week", Int64.Type}, {"Cumulative Unique Count", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

**Orig Data**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you

I am creating all combinations of dates and criteria, appending that to the original table, then using an index to compare to prior row to see if I need to fill down or not

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Criteria One", type text}, {"Criteria Two", type text}, {"Start of Week", type date}, {"Count", Int64.Type}, {"Unique Count in Week", Int64.Type}, {"Cumulative Unique Count", Int64.Type}}),

// get all unique combinations of Criteria1 and Criteria2 and merge it to all combination of dates between max and min dates
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Criteria One", "Criteria Two"}),
Unique_Critera = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"),
Max= Number.From(List.Max(#"Changed Type"[Start of Week])),
Min= Number.From(List.Min(#"Changed Type"[Start of Week])),
Date_Range={ Number.From(List.Min(#"Changed Type"[Start of Week])) .. Number.From(List.Max(#"Changed Type"[Start of Week]))},
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Unique_Critera, "Start of Week", each Date_Range),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom", "Start of Week"),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Start of Week", type date}}),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "DayWeek", each Date.DayOfWeek([Start of Week])),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom1", each ([DayWeek] = 0)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"DayWeek"}),

// remove those on list that exists alrady
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Columns",{"Criteria One", "Criteria Two", "Start of Week"},#"Changed Type",{"Criteria One", "Criteria Two", "Start of Week"},"Table2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Criteria One"}, {"Criteria One.1"}),
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Table2", each ([Criteria One.1] = null)),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{"Criteria One.1"}),

// append that list to original and sort
#"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Changed Type", #"Removed Columns1"}),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Appended Query",{{"Criteria One", Order.Ascending}, {"Criteria Two", Order.Ascending}, {"Start of Week", Order.Ascending}}),

// refer to previous row to see if we need to fill down or leave as null
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each if [Cumulative Unique Count] <> null then [Cumulative Unique Count] else if #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Criteria One]=[Criteria One] and #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Criteria Two]=[Criteria Two] then #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Cumulative Unique Count] else null),
#"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Cumulative Unique Count", "Index"}),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns2",{{"Custom", "Cumulative Unique Count"}})
in #"Renamed Columns"
```

You could I suppose also merge the original data into the new table and proceed from there saving a few rows